# Finding the root vertex in an ordered graph using adjacency matrix in O(N)

Tags: matrix, graph-algorithm

I have an adjacency matrix for an [ordered graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_graph) and I need to find vertex to which all others have edge to (in it's row there are all 1s except for the diagonal):

If this is adjacency matrix:

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
1 1 0
```

the algorithm should yield vertex 3.

Suppose that there is at least one vertex like this.

Solution in O(N^2) (N being the number of vertices) is trivial, but how can this be done in O(N)?

Comment: I have data already loaded in memory, I know it should be possible, just don't know how to do it

Comment: I did some googling but didn't find anything useful and I am not able to make up anything on my one, that's reason why I am writing here

Comment: I just saw that you say that this is an "[ordered graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_graph)". That makes the matrix "special" - if you find out, what's so special about it, you will see how you can "traverse" the matrix in order to get to the right vertex.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. You can for example have 10 vertices which are chained. In this case, there are no vertices to which all others have edge. Do you have some particular constraints on this matrix?

Comment: yes, I can suppose that there is at least one such a vertex that has edges from all others.

Comment: A way to reduce it would be to scan a random column (equivalent of "which vertices are pointing to this vertex?"). If `0`, you have it. Else, you scan each line on which you found `1` during the previous scan. Bascially, it is equivalent to taking a random node and assume that the node you are searching is necessarily among its parents.

Comment: is the graph acyclic?

Answer (score 2):

Preconditions:

- the graph is an [ordered graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_graph)
- there is one vertex that all other vertices have an in-edge to

Since the edges need to induce a total ordering, the vertex that needs to be found is the "smallest" vertex, it does not have any out edges, because this would be to one of the other edges that it is already connected to and that would lead to a cycle, which is not allowed in an ordered graph.

Also the graph needs to be connected, therefor all paths need to lead to the smallest vertex, which brings us to this algorithm:

1. start with the set of all rows as possible candidates
2. choose one vertex from the set and iterate over possible edges to the remaining candidates.

   - If there is an edge to the candidate, remove the candidate from step 2 from the list and continue at 2 with the new candidate.
   - If there is no edge to that vertex remove the target candidate from the candidate set and continue with the next possible edge.
   - if no candidate is left, the current vertex is the one you were looking for

Since each step can be carried out in O(1) and in each step the set of remaining candidates is reduced, the running time should be O(N).

Answer (score 0):

An ordered graph is a graph with a total order over its vertices. There is no other requirement, in particular, it does not restrict where the edges can go. So the answer to the question is that you sometimes cannot do better than O(N^2): Consider an adjacency matrix where one row has all non-diagonal entries equal to one and all other rows have exactly one zero non-diagonal entry. Unless you are extremely lucky, you need to go through nearly the whole adjacency matrix to find out which row has no non-diagonal zero.

So I assume that you mean a directed graph admitting a **[topological ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_ordering)**. That is, a [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (DAG). In that case, Sebastian already answered it, but since the answer is not accepted, let me try to explain it hopefully more clearly.

If a vertex in a DAG has incoming edges from every other vertex, then it has no outgoing edges, since these would form a cycle of length 2. In other words, its corresponding column has only zeros. Such a vertex is called a **universal sink** and there is a well-known O(N) algorithm for finding it.

**General algorithm:**

1. candidates := {0,1,...,N-1}
2. while |candidates| > 1 do:

   - arbitrarily select candidates u and v
   - if (u,v) is an edge, remove u from cadidates, else remove v from candidates
3. test if the last remaining candidate is a universal sink

If you know that your graph has a universal sink, then the last step is unnecesary.

The number of iterations of the while loop is N-1, because every iteration removes one vertex from the set of candidates. The algorithm is correct, because it removes only vertices that cannot be universal sinks - either the removed vertex has an outgoing edge or it does not have an incoming edge from some vertex.

In the code below, you can notice that we do not hold the list of candidates explicitly. The list of candidates in step *i* of the for-cycle is *{candidate, i, i+1, ..., N-1}* and the selected candidates *u* and *v* are *candidate* and *i*.

```
// step 2
int candidate = 0;
for(int i=1; i<N; i++)
{
  if(edge[candidate][i] == 1)
      candidate = i;
}
// step 3
bool no_sink = false;
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
  if(candidate  != i && (edge[candidate][i] == 1 || edge[i][candidate]==0))
      no_sink = true; 
}
if(no_sink)
    printf("No universal sink.");
else
    printf("The universal sink is %d.", candidate);
```